# Can I set the location of httpd.config file via a shell variable ?

Tags: apache, shell, config

This maybe a nub question, but can I set the http config file location via a shell environment variable ? Anyone knows what it is ?

Comment: you need to include more context. Right now, all we can say is "here is how you set a shell variable, `var="string_value"`. Good luck.

Comment: hi shelter.. thanks. I'm really looking for the variable name. I scoured the apache docs, but came up empty. Before I dive into the apache server code, I was hoping someone lived this before me.

Comment: Again, you're not really providing enough context. For instance, what OS are you running on?Update your question (not in comments) with this info and others more experienced may offer help. You'll see all of the variable names there. . . .  if you have the `ps` util. available, find the running process, then use the `ps` option that displays the environment for that specific PID.  . . . Good luck.

Comment: As an addendum to what @shellter said, I'd like to know what you're trying to achieve. Like maybe, do you want to set an environment variable containing a string pointing to the location of the config file? Which is required to be read by some other entity?

Comment: Hi shelter, for context it doesn't make a difference.. If I disclose the purpose, I'll get  4-5 alternatives to my question as an answer, and not answers to the question I've asked.

Comment: @alok, yes you ar paraphrasing my question. "Like maybe, do you want to set an environment variable containing a string pointing to the location of the config file?"   That would be the purpose using the environment variable to tell httpd where to find the config file. I thought that would have been obvious by the question and tags in the comment.

Comment: You haven't been out in the world enough if you can't take at least two meanings of it, or more! Ok, here are the specific parameters I would like to know: 1) Where are you setting the variable from? Interactive BaSH? 2) Where is this going to be referred from? Same shell / Some other shell / Some other process / a different process / a different PC? 3) What is about the name you were mentioning to shellter? I didn't understand, are you looking for a variable name?

Comment: Hi Alok, I have a solution to the issue. First there is no shell environment variable used by httpd to point to the httpd.config file.  If under windows,  the solution is to create a shell environment variable and reference the variable in the command line when creating the service. If using DS and windows, the value of the variable value can be set via the  DS tree.. Under linux, it not as elegant, but still works using LDAP and a similar method.